# Finding the number of capital letters in a word grouped by letter

Tags: c#, unit-testing, comparative-review

Please see the code options below:

**Client App** - this is the same for both options

```
LetterCounter lc = new LetterCounter("HeLLo");
```

**Option 1**

```
class LetterCounter
    {
        string _Word;
        List<LetterQuantities> letterQuantities;

        //Other functions will be here.

        public LetterCounter(string Word)
        {
            _Word = Word;
            LetterQuantities lq = new LetterQuantities();
            letterQuantities = lq.GetCapialLetterQuantities(Word);
        }
    }

    class LetterQuantities
    {
        int _Quantity;
        char _Letter;

        public LetterQuantities()
        {
        }

        public LetterQuantities(int Quantity, char Letter)
        {
            _Quantity = Quantity;
            _Letter = Letter;
        }

        public List<LetterQuantities> GetCapialLetterQuantities(string Word)
        {
            List<LetterQuantities> letterQuantitiesList = new List<LetterQuantities>();
            for (char c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; c++)
            {
                int count = Word.Split(c).Length - 1;
                if (count > 0)
                {
                    LetterQuantities lq = new LetterQuantities(count, c);
                    letterQuantitiesList.Add(lq);
                }
            }
            return letterQuantitiesList;
        }
    }
```

**Option 2**

```
class LetterCounter
    {
        string _Word;
        List<KeyValuePair<char, int>> LetterQuantities = new List<KeyValuePair<char, int>>();

        //Other functions will be here.

        public LetterCounter(string Word)
        {
            _Word = Word;
            GetCapialLetterQuantities();
        }

        public void GetCapialLetterQuantities()
        {
            for (char c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; c++)
            {
                int count = _Word.Split(c).Length - 1;
                if (count > 0)
                {
                    LetterQuantities.Add(new KeyValuePair<char,int>(c,count));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The concerns I have are:

1) Option 1: LetterQuantities returns a list of itself.  Not sure this is ideal.  However, it is how a Tree data structure works.
2) Option 2: This is simpler.  However, I am not sure whether 'Letter' is a valid key. 
3) I am not sure whether the object(s) should be Singletons as they are value objects rather than entity objects.

I believe I should use option 1 from a TDD point of view.

Comment: What about `"abc123".Count(char.IsLetter)` ? Oh I see. Could you please clarify what your code is suposed to do? Otherwise other people will have the same problem as me/

Comment: @ Bruno Costa, I am trying to understand whether to use a class or a dictionary for the LetterQuantities.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is that I wouldn't use either of those approaches. Counting the number of occurrences on a string isn't complex enough that requires a class of it's own. An extension method however would be a reasonable way to do it, as well as using the `LINQ` to get the desired result:

```
public static IDictionary<char, int> GetOcurrences(this string value){
    return value.GroupBy(c => c)
        .ToDictionary(c => c.Key, c => c.Count());
}
```

Or to count only letters

```
public static IDictionary<char, int> GetOcurrences(this string value){
    return value
        .Where(char.IsLetter)
        .GroupBy(c => c)
        .ToDictionary(c => c.Key, c => c.Count());
}
```

Or to count only capital letters

```
public static IDictionary<char, int> GetOcurrences(this string value){
    return value
        .Where(c => c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
        .GroupBy(c => c)
        .ToDictionary(c => c.Key, c => c.Count());
}
```

Or to count only letters provided by a parameter

```
public static IDictionary<char, int> GetOcurrences(this string value, string filter){
    return value
        .Where(c => filter.Contains(c))
        .GroupBy(c => c)
        .ToDictionary(c => c.Key, c => c.Count());
}
```

Comment: Is a character suitable for a key? Thanks

Comment: @w0051977 Yes it is, as suitable as an integer, or a string

Comment: thanks.  Is a decimal (currency) suitable for a key?

Comment: @w0051977 I am not totally sure about that one but I never seen it being used as a key. If you need to use it has a key you might be doing something wrong as well. The problem is that even if the decimal type might implement a good `GetHashCode` there some cases where you have a key `0.3333` present on the dictionary but try to fetch `0.33333333333333` instead

Comment: The key would be for currency groupings i.e. 50M,20M,10M,5M,2M,1M,05M,0.2M,0.1M,0.05M,0.02M,0.01M.

Comment: If you had to choose option one or option two from my question, then which would it be?

Comment: @w0051977 Option 2 is the closest but it is still too clumsy. You can compute the result on a method and return that result on that same method, which was what I did. I can not guarantee that decimal dictionary will work but I don't find any problems atm. Try it

Comment: I have asked a similar question here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/164772/decimal-quantities-needed-to-meet-cost.  Thought I would let you know in case you have chance to take a look.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to use `IEnumerable<char>` instead of `string`. It's more generic solution.

---

I like the @bruno-costa' answer, but instead of `Dictionary` I would suggest to use just array of `int`.

```
    public static int[] GetOccurrences(IEnumerable<char> value) {
        int[] result = new int[char.MaxValue + 1];
        foreach (char c in value) {
            result[c]++;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static int[] GetCapialLetterOccurrences(IEnumerable<char> value) {
        int[] capialLetterOccurrences = new int['Z' - 'A' + 1];
        int[] letterOccurrences = GetOccurrences(value);
        Array.Copy(letterOccurrences, 'A', capialLetterOccurrences, 0, capialLetterOccurrences.Length);
        return capialLetterOccurrences;
    }
```

---

You may say that \$2^{16}\$ bytes is an overkill for such task and I agree

```
    public static int[] GetCapialLetterOccurrences_upd(IEnumerable<char> value) {
        int[] result = new int['Z' - 'A' + 1];
        foreach (char c in value) {
            if ('A' <=c && c <= 'Z') {
                result[c]++;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: creating an array of 2^16 entries doesn't seem to be a good idea.

Comment: It perfectly fits to modern L1 cache, so do not expect any performance overhead. You actually can use 2^('Z'-'A'+1) for capitals with prefiltering.

Comment: @BrunoCosta but I agree with you - for finding capital letters occurrences it's an overkill.

Comment: Did you mean `log2(2^('Z'-'A'+1))` = `('Z'-'A'+1)` ;)

Comment: @BrunoCosta OMG)) Of course I meant 
"It perfectly fits to modern L1 cache, so do not expect any performance overhead. You actually can use 'Z'-'A'+1 for capitals with prefiltering." Sorry!