# Decimal Quantities needed to meet cost

Tags: c#, unit-testing, comparative-review, formatting, change-making-problem

I asked this question recently: [Finding the number of capital letters in a word grouped by letter](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/164688/finding-the-number-of-capital-letters-in-a-word-grouped-by-letter).  The answerer answered my specific question so I have marked it as answered.  However, I would like to ask a similar question.  The reason I am asking a similar question is because the code in my last question was too simple i.e. simple string manipulations.  Therefore I have made this code a little more complex in the hope that my question about rich domain models (question one below) will be answered.

The code below calculates the currency that should be provided in order to meet a cost going from highest to lowest.  For example, if the cost is: 152.45, then the following decimals (unit of currencies are required):

```
3 * £50 note
1* £2 coin
2 * £0.20
1 * 0.5
```

**Client App -** this is the same for both options

```
DecimalCounter dc = new DecimalCounter(1552.78M);
```

**Option 1**

```
   public class DecimalCounter
    {
        public decimal Cost { get; set; }
        List<KeyValuePair<decimal, int>> DecimalsToUseList;

        public DecimalCounter(decimal _Cost)
        {
            Cost = _Cost;
            DecimalQuantities cq = new DecimalQuantities();
            DecimalsToUseList = cq.GetDecimalsToUse(_Cost);
        }

        public class DecimalQuantities
        {
            int _Quantity;
            decimal _Amount;

            public List<decimal> GetDecimalList()
            {
                List<decimal> DecimalList = new List<decimal>();
                DecimalList = new List<decimal>();
                DecimalList.Add(50M);
                DecimalList.Add(20M);
                DecimalList.Add(10M);
                DecimalList.Add(5M);
                DecimalList.Add(2M);
                DecimalList.Add(1M);
                DecimalList.Add(0.5M);
                DecimalList.Add(0.2M);
                DecimalList.Add(0.1M);
                DecimalList.Add(0.05M);
                DecimalList.Add(0.02M);
                DecimalList.Add(0.01M);
                return DecimalList;
            }

            public List<KeyValuePair<decimal, int>> GetDecimalsToUse(decimal Cost)
            {
                List<KeyValuePair<decimal, int>> DecimalQuantitiesList = new List<KeyValuePair<decimal, int>>();

                List<decimal> DecimalList = GetDecimalList();
                int ReadCount = 0;
                decimal QuantityOfDecimal = 0;
                foreach (decimal DecimalAmount in DecimalList)
                {
                    if (Cost >= DecimalAmount)
                    {
                        QuantityOfDecimal = Cost / DecimalAmount;
                        if (QuantityOfDecimal > 0)
                        {
                            int QuantityOfDecimalInt = (int)Math.Floor(QuantityOfDecimal);
                            if (ReadCount == 0)
                            {
                                DecimalQuantitiesList = new List<KeyValuePair<decimal, int>>();
                            }
                            ReadCount += 1;
                            //KeyValuePair<decimal, int> test = new KeyValuePair<decimal, int>(DecimalAmount, QuantityOfDecimalInt);
                            DecimalQuantitiesList.Add(new KeyValuePair<decimal, int>(DecimalAmount, QuantityOfDecimalInt));
                            Cost = Cost - (QuantityOfDecimalInt * DecimalAmount);
                        }
                    }
                }
                return DecimalQuantitiesList;

            }

        }
    }
```

**Option 2**

```
public class DecimalCounter
    {
        public decimal Cost { get; set; }
        private List<decimal> DecimalList { get; set; }
        List<KeyValuePair<decimal, int>> DecimalQuantitiesList;

        public DecimalCounter(decimal _Cost)
        {
            Cost = _Cost;
            GetDecimalList();
            GetDecimalsToUse();
        }

        public void GetDecimalList()
        {
            DecimalList = new List<decimal>();
            DecimalList.Add(50M);
            DecimalList.Add(20M);
            DecimalList.Add(10M);
            DecimalList.Add(5M);
            DecimalList.Add(2M);
            DecimalList.Add(1M);
            DecimalList.Add(0.5M);
            DecimalList.Add(0.2M);
            DecimalList.Add(0.1M);
            DecimalList.Add(0.05M);
            DecimalList.Add(0.02M);
            DecimalList.Add(0.01M);
        }

        private void GetDecimalsToUse()
        {
            decimal CostOutStanding=Cost;
            int ReadCount = 0;
            decimal QuantityOfDecimal = 0;
            foreach (decimal DecimalAmount in DecimalList)
            {
                if (CostOutStanding >= DecimalAmount)
                {
                    QuantityOfDecimal = CostOutStanding / DecimalAmount;
                    if (QuantityOfDecimal > 0)
                    {
                        int QuantityOfDecimalInt = (int)Math.Floor(QuantityOfDecimal);
                        if (ReadCount == 0)
                        {
                            DecimalQuantitiesList = new List<KeyValuePair<decimal, int>>();
                        }
                        ReadCount += 1;
                        //KeyValuePair<decimal, int> test = new KeyValuePair<decimal, int>(DecimalAmount, QuantityOfDecimalInt);
                        DecimalQuantitiesList.Add(new KeyValuePair<decimal, int>(DecimalAmount, QuantityOfDecimalInt));
                        CostOutStanding = CostOutStanding - (QuantityOfDecimalInt * DecimalAmount);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

**Analysis**

The difference between the two options is that option one stores the decimal quantities in a dictionary and in option 2, there is a class for decimal quantities.

1. Which option is "better" from a Domain Driven Development (Rich Domain Model)/unit testing point of view? (this is the most important question).  Is there a better option than the options I have provided?
2. In option 1; can I use a decimal as the key of the KeyValuePair? The answerer of my previous question (see hyperlink in first paragraph) said I can use strings and integers but was unsure about decimals.  I believe I can because I believe the decimals are always unique.
3. Should I be using Singletons for these types? They are value types and they do not have an ID so I believe I should.

Comment: For speed check out the integer version I added to my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This applies everywhere but parameters to methods should be `camelCase`:

> ```
> public DecimalCounter(decimal _Cost)
> ```

should be

```
public DecimalCounter(decimal cost)
```

I'd advise you to look at the [naming guidelines on msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002(v=vs.110).aspx).

---

I'd say that neither of your solutions are particularly good from either a rich domain or a TDD point of view. It's all too coupled.

---

Why does `DecimalCounter` provide it's own list of denominations? It's also poorly named.

---

Why not abstract the available denominations?

```
public interface ICurrency 
{
    string Name { get; }
    IEnumerable<int> AvailableDenominations { get; }
}
```

Then your `CurrencyCalculator`:

```
public class CurrencyCalculator
{
    private readonly ICurrency currency;

    public CurrencyCalculator(ICurrency currency)
    {
        this.currency = currency;
    }

    public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, int>> CalculateDenominationsFor(int cost) 
    {
        var target = cost;
        foreach (var denomination in currency.AvailableDenominations.OrderByDescending(a => a))
        {
           var numberRequired = target / denomination;
           if (numberRequired > 0)
           {
               yield return new KeyValuePair<int, int>(denomination, numberRequired);
           }
           target = target - (numberRequired * denomination); 
        }
    } 
}
```

You'll notice that I've converted everything to `int`. If you just work in the base unit for a currency (e.g. pence, cents etc.) then you don't have to work with `decimal` at all.

This more decoupled code adds a few benefits:

1. You can test against different currencies which have different denominations available
2. `CalculateDenominationsFor` returns a value which makes unit testing easier

## Update

I added an implementation to the `CalculateDenominationsFor` method and here's a working example:

```
public class Gbp : ICurrency
{
    public string Name { get; } = "Pound Sterling";

    public IEnumerable<int> AvailableDenominations {get;} = 
    new List<int> 
    {
        1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000, 2000, 5000
    };
}

void Main()
{
    var calculator = new CurrencyCalculator(new Gbp());
    var result = calculator.CalculateDenominationsFor(123);
    // { { 100, 1 }, { 20, 1 }, { 2, 1 }, { 1, 1 } }
}
```

## Update 2

One thing I didn't mention was that by working in the base unit with an `int` the maximum value you can calculate is quite limited. If you need to work with bigger numbers, use `long` instead :)

Also, if efficiency is key, you can change the code to only adjust the target value when you need to. It won't make a big difference but I think the code makes more sense to look at anyway.

```
if (numberRequired > 0)
{
    yield return new KeyValuePair<int, int>(denomination, numberRequired);
    target = target - (numberRequired * denomination); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Where is ICurrency implemented?  Could you change all your references of Currency to Decimal e.g. DecimalCalculator.

Comment: @w0051977 I haven't implemented `ICurrency`. It's example/pseudo code. Why would you call it `DecimalXyz` when you're talking about currency? There's no reason you couldn't but given that I also switched to `int` decimal would be a really weird choice of name.

Comment: Thanks, I assume you would have an implementation of ICurrency for each currency type e.g. pounds,dollars,yen etc.  Then you inject the ICurrency into the calculator.  Have I understood that correctly? +1 for the comprehensive answer.

Comment: @w0051977 - that's it exactly.

Comment: thanks.  One more thing - why use an integer rather than a decimal?

Comment: @w0051977 - Mmm, I felt like I had good reasons before but I can't remember them now. The performance will be better by working with `int` but that's really not a good reason to prefer it.

Comment: thanks.  Please let me know once you remember and then I will mark your answer.  Also, I am using a WCF web service so I cannot return an IEnumerable for currency.AvailableDenominations.  Which of the following would you return: 1) IEnumerable of KeyValuePair or 2) List of type?

Comment: @w0051977 - I updated the code. I think I thought that using `int` would make the algorithm easier to write and read... You can be the judge of that.

Comment: Why did you inject Currency into the constructor ? Why not just pass it to the method (CalculateDenominationsFor)? Thanks again.

Comment: @w0051977 - I thought it was more useful to be able to create an instance and use it multiple times rather than having to pass currency each time. There isn't a strong reason either way.

Answer (score 3):

There are somethings that I didn't mention on my last answer but perhaps I should mention now. One bad thing about this two implementations is that both classes take a value on the constructor.

What this means is that you are obligated to create multiple instances of the class if you want to make multiple calculations. This is not a problem per se because instantiation is not problematic performance wise and you can bet that the garbage collector will be occupied with a whole lot of other objects besides this.

The point is that having object state (`DecimalQuantitiesList`, `DecimalList`, `DecimalQuantitiesList`) does not make sense for this kind of operations.

Instead you could see them as some kind of mathematical functions that receive a bunch of parameters and return a value.

There are other issues on the code. Per instance it would be sensible to have a static list with the possible values instead of having that `GetDecimalList` method:

```
private static readonly IEnumerable<decimal> ValidMoney = new []{50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1, 
    0.5, 0.2, 0.1, 0.05, 0.02, 0.01};
```

Also `(int)Math.Floor(QuantityOfDecimal)` could simply become `(int)QuantityOfDecimal` due to truncation.

So this would lead into the following structure (if you really want to have a class for it):

```
public class DecimalCounter{
   private static readonly IEnumerable<decimal> ValidMoney = new []{50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1, 
        0.5, 0.2, 0.1, 0.05, 0.02, 0.01};

   public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<decimal, int>> GetDecimalQuantities(decimal value){
       //implementation goes here
   }
}
```

As you can see this looks already completely different from both approaches that you have. There is no constructor, the class is able to process multiple values, the possible values are easily recognized and are instantiated only once in run-time. It just looks cleaner.

However I would argue that this can also go into some kind of Mathematical utility class as a static method, perhaps without being an extension method.

```
public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<decimal, int>> ValueToUsableTokens(decimal value, params decimal[] tokens){
    if(value == 0){
        return new Dictionary<decimal, int>();
    }

    var result = new Dictionary<decimal, int>();
    for(var i = 0; i < tokens.Length; ++i){
        var quotient = (int)(value / tokens[i]);
        if(quotient > 0){
            result[tokens[i]] = (int)quotient;
        }
        value = value - quotient * tokens[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

I took the freedom of adding a parameters so this particular method is not dependent on using those specific values. Usage would be:

```
ValueToUsableTokens(152.45M, new []{50M, 20M, 10M, 5M, 2M, 1M, 
    0.5M, 0.2M, 0.1M, 0.05M, 0.02M, 0.01M})
```

Comment: Thanks for answering again.  All your answers suggest using static functions.  This is what I dislike about static functions: http://misko.hevery.com/2008/12/15/static-methods-are-death-to-testability/

Comment: @w0051977 I am aware of all concerns of using static functions. But the reality is that they just work as fine in this kind of scenarios. Plus it is really easy to drop out of being static if you want to.

Comment: @w0051977 There's also nothing stopping you from having both a static and non static methods, perhaps in different classes.

Comment: were would you put the validation for the cost (value)? +1.

Comment: @w0051977  I wouldn’t. If you had paid attention I changed the algorithm in such way that “validation “ is no longer needed. Or should I say it was replaced by a different one.

Answer (score 3):

There are already answers about naming and other conventions so I won't mention them again.

---

I agree that the `DecimalCounter` has too many responsibilities which currently are:

- denominating
- grouping
- counting

This should be splitted into smaller pieces to improve its testability however I wouldn't go with a full currency class/interfaces for this yet because I think it's not necessasry. Instead I would try to make it more LINQ friendly thus I'm going to suggest an extension that I call `Split`, just like the `string.Split` but this one is for decimals.

```
public static IEnumerable<decimal> Split(this decimal value, IEnumerable<decimal> denominations)
{
    ...
}
```

It should just return an `IEnumerable<decimal>` that gives you a lot of freedom to deal with.

You can count it, you can sum it, you can group it, you can do all kind of LINQ stuff with it if you want.

Example:

```
var denominations = new[] { 50M, 20M, 10M, 5M, 2M, 1M, 0.5M, 0.2M, 0.1M, 0.05M, 0.02M, 0.01M };

var value = 152.78m;
var denominated = value.Split(denominations);
var oldValue = denominated.Sum();
var denominationCounts = 
    denominated
        .GroupBy(x => x).Select(g => new 
        { 
            Denomination = g.Key, 
            Count = g.Count() 
        });
```

This means do **just** what needs to be done, this is, **denominate**. Everything else you can do with what's already there so let LINQ do the rest.

---

Lastly I changed your algorithm. I don't think you need to multiply or divide anything. Just subtract the next largest denomination until there is nothing left.

```
public static IEnumerable<decimal> Split(this decimal value, IEnumerable<decimal> denominations)
{
    foreach (var denomination in denominations.OrderByDescending(d => d))
    {
        while ((value -= denomination) >= 0)
        {
            yield return denomination;
        }
        // Did we denominate too much?
        if (value < 0) 
        {
            // Undo the last denomination.
            value += denomination; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with your last suggestion is if you are dealing with big quantities (i.e billions 1 000 000 000). If you put that into 50 note bills you would get 20 000 000 iterations. Conclusion: Let the ALU make the division

Comment: @BrunoCosta perhaps but it's an insane number ;-) and there's always one for every algorithm that brings it to its knees.

Comment: Well it's not necessarily an insane number, if you deal with things like GDP or Country debt. With 1 000 000 you still get 20 000 iterations, which put you into lottery prizes,  wealth  of a company / rich person, or a price of a mansion with all bells and whistles.

Comment: @BrunoCosta Lottery is not paid out in bills.

Comment: @Paparazzi I never said it was nor I suggested it was.

Comment: @t3chb0t, Would you do any validation on the decimal passed to your split function e.g. make sure it is greater than zero; has two decimal places etc?

Answer (score 1):

I know code only answer are frowned upon but I think there is a simpler approach
The count loop is still pretty fast and it makes for simpler math
Even with 1111111552.78M it runs in less than 3 seconds

```
public class DecimalCounter
{
    private static readonly IEnumerable<decimal> ValidMoney = 
                   new[]{50M, 20M, 10M, 5M, 2M, 1M, 0.5M, 0.2M, 0.1M, 0.05M, 0.02M, 0.01M};

    public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<decimal, int>> GetDecimalQuantities(decimal value)
    {
        int count;
        foreach(decimal note in ValidMoney)
        {
            count = 0;
            while(value >= note)
            {
                count++;
                value -= note;
            }
            if(count > 0)
            {
                yield return new KeyValuePair<decimal, int>(note, count);
            }
            if (value == 0)
                break;
        }
    }
    public DecimalCounter()
    {
        Test();
    }
    private void Test()
    {
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        foreach(KeyValuePair<decimal, int> kvp in GetDecimalQuantities(1552.78M))
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("{0}  {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Debug.WriteLine("DONE " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
}
```

I am getting grief on speed
So I wrote one for speed - integer math is faster

```
public class DecimalIntCounter
{
    private static readonly IEnumerable<int> IntMoney = new[] { 5000, 2000, 1000, 500, 200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1 };
    public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<decimal, int>> GetDecimalQuantities(decimal value)
    {
        int count;
        long valueInt = (long)(value * 100);
        foreach (int note in IntMoney)
        {
            count = (int)(valueInt / note);
            if (count > 0)
            {
                yield return new KeyValuePair<decimal, int>( note / 100M, count);
                valueInt = valueInt % note;
            }
            if (value == 0)
                break;
        }
    }
    public DecimalIntCounter()
    {
        Test();
    }
    private void Test()
    {
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        foreach (KeyValuePair<decimal, int> kvp in GetDecimalQuantities(1111111552.78M))  // 1552.78M
        {
            int i = kvp.Value;
            decimal d = kvp.Key;
            //Debug.WriteLine("{0}  {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Debug.WriteLine("DONE " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
}
```

Comment: This code has the same potential problem as t3chb0t's solution above. It will have a really poor performance for large input values due to `while(value >= note)` loop.

Comment: @NikitaB How big of numbers do you think this would be used for?  Even 1111111552.78M runs in less than 3 seconds.   I don't call that really poor performance.

Comment: @Paparazzi Nowadays anythings that takes over 10milliseconds on the windows operating system is considered to be time consuming and is usually a candidate to run asynchronously. You may think 3 seconds is nothing on human time and you are right. But I will let you know that 3 seconds is a lot of CPU time. One of the most expensive operations is hashing a password and even that should take about 1 second to compute (this should take always the same time no matter what your hardware is, at least, if you upgrade it).

Comment: @BrunoCosta 1552.78M runs in 40 ms.   I can live with that.  If you can't that is up to you.

Comment: @Paparazzi Seems reasonable to me. But under 3 seconds is not the same as 40ms

Comment: @Paparazzi you probably forgot to enumerate your implementation. I took 5kk as input, and your code takes 4.5s to execute it 1000 times. Same code using division (OP's original implementation) takes 2ms. I would in fact call it a significant performance difference. LinqPad test: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b9e1f97b4367bf74886a8d2a252bb66e

Comment: @NikitaB Significant difference is not unacceptable performance.  1552.78M runs in 40 ms.  That is acceptable for me.  I did not assert it was faster.  I said simpler.

Comment: @BrunoCosta 1552.78M runs in 40 ms.   If they are really going to use it for very large numbers then yes would performance tune.   I would use integer.

Comment: One thing you are not considering on this discussion though is that could be a requirement to compute this operation n amount of times. Say 50 (a client page size). That could put you into 2 second penalty that wouldn't occur otherwise.

Comment: @BrunoCosta  Let it go.  I agree it is not the most efficient.  Could also just be called a few times with small number.  It is just an example of simple code.

Comment: The only reason I am not up-voting it's because t3chb0t's  gave a similar solution earlier.

Comment: @BrunoCosta Check out the speed version.  By my numbers 3x faster than yours.

Comment: @NikitaB Check out the speed version

Comment: It is indeed faster by a factor of ~1.5 however. Don't forget to warm up your performance tests. But doesn't really matter what the factor is really. I only participated on this whole debate so you would acknowledge that dividing is a better approach if you are dealing with bigger numbers, which you already did. Now I am still not upvoting because you don't state what the improvements of your code are relating to the OP code. we shouldn't be the focus. The Op should though.

Comment: @BrunoCosta LET IT GO.   I never came close to asserting a loop was faster than division.

Comment: @Paparazzi, were would you put the validation for the cost decimal that is passed to the GetDecimalQuantities method? +1.

Answer (score 0):

**Keep it simple**

Here's my code. I wanted to keep it simple. Note the total length of the code vs the length of code posted above. do you find it more understandable? simpler?

**Other implementations possible**

If you wanted to go all out hardcore OOP, then you could add a factory method. But there's really no need at this stage. You could use a dictionary to return the results you were after - simple enough to implement. Or if you wanted to have coins incorporated you could do that. but i wanted to keep it as simple as possible. rather than commenting on your own code, i thought it perhaps more beneficial to you to see how someone else has worked through the same problem.

I **hope it helps** you and all readers too.

**The Class**

```
namespace CoinCounterII
{
    public class CurrencyCounter
    {
        private decimal total;

        public CurrencyCounter(decimal total)
        {
            this.total = total;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Return an array containing all the currency required to total
        /// the relevant amount. The easiest accumulation of notes will be
        /// returned. If you have $20 then i'll give you a $20 note, rather
        /// than 4 x $5 notes. Let's start with $26 as an example. First i'll subtract
        /// the biggest denomination possible: that's $20 so i'm left with $6.
        /// Then i'll subtract the next biggest denomination possible: that's
        /// $5 so i'm left with $1. Then i subtract the next denomination and
        /// I subtract $1 to return 0. I subtract my way to success to finally
        /// return: 25, 5, and 1 in an array. You could return a dictionary if you like
        /// but note the simplicity of the code.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public List<decimal> Change()
        {
            List<decimal> kitty = new List<decimal>();

            while (total > 0)
            {
                // get maximum note you can use to deduct from the total
                // if you wanted to go hardCore OOP then you could return
                // a class method here. Let's call it the money
                // class: Money m = Money.Factory(total)
                // then you would have child classes of
                // $5 notes, $10 notes, $20 notes. But why complicate it
                // let's not extract the class. We can extract it when we have more information
                // in the future.
                decimal legalTenderUnit = TenderAmount();

                kitty.Add(legalTenderUnit);

                // after adding to the kitty don't forget to reduce the
                // total amount owed
                total -= legalTenderUnit;
            }

            return kitty;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Return highest denomination possible to reduce the
        /// total by, given the total amount.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private decimal TenderAmount()
        {
            if (total < 5)
            {
                return 1M;
            }
            else if (total < 10)
            {
                return 5M;
            }
            else if (total < 20)
            {
                return 10M;
            }
            else if (total < 50)
            {
                return 20M;
            }
            else if (total < 100)
            {
                return 50M;
            }
            else
            {
                return 100M;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**My Tests**

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace CoinCounterII
{
    [TestFixture]
    internal class CurrencyCounterTests
    {
        [TestCase]
        public void change_oneDollar_1()
        {
            CurrencyCounter cc = new CurrencyCounter(1M);
            List<decimal> change = cc.Change();

            CollectionAssert.AreEqual(change, new List<decimal>() { 1M });
        }

        [TestCase]
        public void change_twoDollars_2()
        {
            CurrencyCounter cc = new CurrencyCounter(2M);
            List<decimal> change = cc.Change();

            CollectionAssert.AreEqual(change, new List<decimal>() { 1M, 1M });
        }

        [TestCase]
        public void change_25Dollars_25()
        {
            CurrencyCounter cc = new CurrencyCounter(25M);
            List<decimal> change = cc.Change();

            CollectionAssert.AreEqual(change, new List<decimal>() { 20M, 5M });
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT - a polymorphic approach**

if you want to go for polymorphism [here's an approach you can try](https://gist.github.com/BKSpurgeon/6a1453c69d1615ec130a1acc47411e9a). but there's not much benefit to it. hope that helps.